# How to get that UIViewController out of any navigation stack

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, navigationcontroller

How can I get that current instance of UIViewController is not used in any navigation stack and it is not modal view controller? I have a lot of view controllers and some server exchange manager which contains strong references to these view controllers. It is necessary to get information that current view controller was popped from navigation view controller (or modal view controller was closed) and that it shouldn't parse any server response for this view controller.

The solution to check that current view controller hasn't got any rootViewController and navigationViewController is not good enough because current view controller could be rootViewController or it could be without navigationViewController in modal view controller.

Have you got any ideas for that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can also check for the current view controllers `view.superview` property.

Answer (score 1):

I not see any other ways than usage of those 2 methods..

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
[yourServerExchangeManager closeConnectionforViewController:self]
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[yourServerExchangeManager openConnectionforViewController:self]
}
```

Comment: thank you, Darktau, I thought about this solution too, but in that case it is necessary to update all view controllers and it's easy to forget about it somewhere one day